# uninitialized constant StoreController::Yajl Rails app

Tags: ruby, yajl, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've included the `yajl` gem in my `Gemfile` via `gem 'yajl-ruby', '~> 1.1.0'` however upon calling `parser = Yajl::Parser.new` in my store controller I receive the error `uninitialized constant StoreController::Yajl`

If I execute `require 'yajl'` at the beginning of the controller all is well but I was under the impression that the gem should be available to controllers within the application simply by including in the gem file.

Comment: Did you `require` inside the controller class or at the top of the file? Try using a fully-qualified reference: `parser = ::Yajl::Parser.new`

Comment: I did require it inside the controller class and it works fine but I was under the impression that including it within the `Gemfile` was enough to make it available to all classes within the rails application?

Comment: Yeah, `Bundler` ought to take care of it for you. Is there a `Bundler.require` call in your `config/application.rb`? Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: There is  a call
    `if defined?(Bundler)¬
    # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line¬
    Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))¬
    # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line¬
    # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)¬
    end¬`
I have run bundle install but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to indicate to Bundler the main file of the gem with the `require` option:

```
gem 'yajl-ruby', '~> 1.1.0', require: 'yajl'
```

This is necessary for gems whose name is different that their main file name.

See [the Gemfile manual](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html).